# extracting voxels within 8 points / vertices

Tags: matlab, geometry, box, normals, vertices

here's the thing: I have 8 points / vertices in a 3D volume. 
I want to know if a point x is contained within the box whose vertices are given by the 8 points.

Moreover, I know that 4 points lie on a plane parallel (let's call it A) to the y axes, and the other 4 points also lie on another plane parallel (B) to the y axes.

So given A and B, which are the 4x3 matrices of the vertices.

I compute the lines joining the two pair of vertices with lie on the boundary hyperplane of the box

```
    LinesJoiningVertices = 
            [A(2,:) - A(1,:), B(1,:) - A(1,:);
             A(1,:) - A(1,:), A(4,:) - A(1,:);
             A(3,:) - A(4,:), B(4,:) - A(4,:);
             A(2,:) - B(2,:), B(3,:) - B(2,:);
             B(2,:) - B(1,:), B(4,:) - B(1,:);
             A(1,:) - B(1,:), B(4,:) - B(1,:)]
```

and I compute the normals of each boundary hyperplane

```
   for i = 1:6
       normals(i,:) = cross(LinesJoiningVertices(i,1:3), LinesJoiningVertices(i,4:6))
   end
```

Theoretically, a point x within the box should have a negative dot product with each normal (shouldn't it?). 
Practically, it doesn't work. I take a point x I know to be within the box, and the answer is greater that 0 for the first, the third and the fifth normal.

Is there an error in my code? 
Is there an error in my math?

Comment: Have a look at [shape functions](http://www.colorado.edu/engineering/CAS/courses.d/AFEM.d/AFEM.Ch11.d/AFEM.Ch11.pdf).  Calculate the natural coordinates xi, eta, and mu.  If all three of these are between -1 and 1, then the point is inside your box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **FIRST OFF**, let me tell you something.

With two parallel planes any three dimentional polygon containing two subsets of four points lying on one of each of these two planes can be identified with **6 points** only, each 3 of them can represent the plane wich contains one of this polygone's faces.

for any 6 points, {A_0,A_2,A_3} on the plane parallel to the plane constitued by {B_0,B_1,B_2}, a condition is needed for the remaining two  points that allows a polygon, or else, we can be faced to any inconsistently distributed coordinates which forms a random non-linear shape or a circle or anything. [this illustration](http://tube.geogebra.org/student/m1704409) shows which two-by-two same-colored lines are bound to be parallel to give the remaining points as an intersection of these lines.

- **Sencondo,** lets proceed to calculate given last informations as a background.

As a beginning, the points' coordinates can be given either generated by the system:

```
syms x y z
P = [x,y,z]
left_x=0;right_x=4;

for j=0:1, for k=0:1, A((j)*2+k+1,1:3)=[left_x;floor(10*rand());floor(10*rand())];end,end
for j=0:1, for k=0:1, B((j)*2+k+1,1:3)=[right_x;floor(10*rand());floor(10*rand())];end,end
```

or, typed manually

```
syms x y z
P = [x,y,z]


left_x=input('enter first x ');
for j=0:1, for k=0:1*~j,  A((j)*2+k+1,1:3)=[left_x;input(['print y' char((j)*2+k+49) ' ']);input(['print z' char((j)*2+k+49) ' '])];end,end,
right_x=input('enter second x ');
for j=0:1, for k=0:1*~j,  B((j)*2+k+1,1:3)=[right_x;input(['print y' char((j)*2+k+49) ' ']);input(['print z' char((j)*2+k+49) ' '])];end,end,
```

2-  now we calculate which of these points are nearer to the y-axix (closer), which are nearer to x-axix (lower), to find equations of 4 virtual planes constituted by each 3 points.

```
close_right_point=B((B(:,3)==min(B(:,3))),:)

far_right_point=B((B(:,3)==max(B(:,3))),:)

if(numel(close_right_point(:,1))==1)
temp=B((B(:,3)==min(B(B(:,3)~=min(B(:,3)),3))) ,:);
middler_points(2,:)=temp(1,:);
else
middler_points(2,:)=close_right_point(2,:);
end




closer_point=middler_points(middler_points(:,3)==min(middler_points(1,3),middler_points(2,3)),:)
if(numel(closer_point(:,1))==1)
further_point=middler_points(middler_points(:,3)==max(middler_points(1,3),middler_points(2,3)),:)
else
further_point=closer_point(2,:)
end


close_normal = cross(closer_point(1,:)-close_right_point(1,:), closer_point(1,:)-close_left_point(1,:))

close_plane=dot(close_normal,P-closer_point)



far_normal = cross(further_point-far_right_point(1,:), further_point-far_left_point(1,:))

far_plane=dot(far_normal,P-further_point)









low_left_point=A((A(:,2)==min(A(:,2))),:)


if(numel(low_left_point(:,1))==1)
temp=A((A(:,2)==min(A(A(:,2)~=min(A(:,2)),2))),:);
average_points(1,:)=temp(1,:);
else
average_points(1,:)=low_left_point(2,:);
end

high_left_point=A((A(:,2)==max(A(:,2))),:)




low_right_point=B((B(:,2)==min(B(:,2))),:)

high_right_point=B((B(:,2)==max(B(:,2))),:)


if(numel(low_right_point(:,1))==1)
temp=B((B(:,2)==min(B(B(:,2)~=min(B(:,2)),2))),:);
average_points(2,:)=temp(1,:);
else
average_points(2,:)=low_right_point(2,:);
end



lower_point=average_points(average_points(:,2)==min(average_points(1,2),average_points(2,2)),:)
if(numel(lower_point(:,1))==1)
higher_point=average_points(average_points(:,2)==max(average_points(1,2),average_points(2,2)),:)
else
higher_point=lower_point(2,:);
end



low_normal = cross( lower_point(1,:)-low_right_point(1,:), lower_point(1,:)-low_left_point(1,:))

low_plane=dot(low_normal,P-lower_point)



high_normal = cross( higher_point-high_right_point(1,:), higher_point-high_left_point(1,:))

high_plane=dot(high_normal,P-higher_point)
```

note that, *normals* are perpendicular vectors to the plane they represent, the equation of any plane is extracted from the normal vector.

[image]

[this](http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1713613) is how the diagram is shown, see the parallel planes and 6 dynamic points that sufficiently constitue any 3D polygone.

3- having almost Finished with that, keeping on to next stage, where we receive coordinates of a desired point by user-input:

```
X=input('enter X ')
Y=input('enter Y ')
Z=input('enter Z ')
```

then, checking out if the point dont go beyond the extreme right, or left, relating to the two parallel planes with y-axis

```
if (X>right_x)
'out-bounds'
return;
end


if (X<left_x)
'out-bounds'
return;
end
```

then, after drawing a virtual line crossing this point parallelising y-axis, we make sure that this point stays always between the segment formed by this line's intersection with the higher and lower virual planes as [this simulation shows](http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1713737)

```
if Z> str2num(char(regexp(evalc(['x=' num2str(X) ';y=' num2str(Y) ';' char(solve(far_plane,z))]),'(\d+.\d*)','match')))
'out-bounds'
return;
end


if Z< str2num(char(regexp(evalc(['x=' num2str(X) ';y=' num2str(Y) ';' char(solve(close_plane,z))]),'(\d+.\d*)','match')))
'out-bounds'
return;
end


if Y> str2num(char(regexp(evalc(['x=' num2str(X) ';z=' num2str(Z) ';' char(solve(high_plane,y))]),'(\d+.\d*)','match')))
'out-of-bounds'
return;
end


if Y< str2num(char(regexp(evalc(['x=' num2str(X) ';z=' num2str(Z) ';' char(solve(low_plane,y))]),'(\d+.\d*)','match')))
'out-of-bounds'
return;
end
```

4- Finalising all this, you can check the validity of this solution using this data-input set

```
0
0
0
6
5.6
0
5.05
4
0
0
6.51
-0.16
6.33
3.59
```

then floatting point

```
1
2
3
```

success!, you can see/modify/check results using this [simulation](http://tube.geogebra.org/m/1712349) by clicking on any point, then change definition text-field with any parameter, you can drag points too.

Answer (score 1):

You have all the positions of your different points, and the position of the point `x`. Imagine a centre point being `(0,0,0)` and your points forming a cube around it. Make all the exterior faces of your cube, like you have done with the `linesJoiningVertices` but with `faces`. You should have 6 exterior `faces`.

Now you have to check if your `x` point is before or after every `face` of your cube. If the point is before every `face`, it is contained within the cube. This works for non cubes too.

Comment: That's what I'm already doing, isn't it? Each normal is the representation of a face.

Comment: Yes, it is. The problem is: It won't always give a negative dot product with each normal, this is what i was meaning with "before the face"
If your face is on the left of your x point, it's gonna give a positive dot product.. Am I wrong ?

Comment: As you suggest, the orientation of the normal to each face is with respect to the face's "local" coordinate system.  You have to make sure you know which sign you want for each of the 6 faces (well, really four, since it's trivial to check in the y-direction).

Comment: Not that trivial, I took the cube as example but it can be any figure !